# How to change url for some sites automatically in Firefox 3

Tags: configuration, firefox-3

I want some particular urls like "springer.com" to automatically convert to "springer.com.proxy1.mycollege.edu". The second url takes me to springer site through my college library gateway; I am able to access some parts that would otherwise be restricted.

Is there some way to convert the url as above automatically in firefox 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could use your hosts file to trick firefox into looking for springer.com in the right place.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file

Answer (score 1):

You can use Greasemonkey for such task.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem is to run a web proxy like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), configure authentication against your campus LDAP directory, and use a [Proxy auto-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file to make the browser go through your proxy.